# Can the rank of the differential of a Lipschitz map decrease in a small neighbourhood?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lipschitz-functions, geometric-measure-theory

Is there an example for a Lipschitz map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ which is differentiable at $x_o$, with $\operatorname{rank} Df(x_o)=k$, such that there is no open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ where $\operatorname{rank} Df \ge k$ (wherever it is defined on $U$).

Note that by the Rademacher theorem $f$ is differentiable a.e. Of course, if $f$ was $C^1$, then such a neighbourhood would always exist.

I am not even sure what happens when $m=n=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be defined as $f(x)=x+x^2\sin(x^{-1})$ if $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$. $f$ is differentiable, but not $C^1$, and globally Lipschitz. $f'(0)=1$, but on every neighborhood of $0$ there are points where $f'$ vanishes.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. However, your function $f$ is not really globally Lipschitz on all $\mathbb{R}$ (there is no constant $C>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|  \le C|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$), since the derivative $f'$ is not bounded. However, $f$ is Lipschitz on intervals $(-a,a)$ for every $a>0$, where the Lipschitz constant depends on $a$. I am satisfied with this solution (I was really more interested in the local phenomenon than the global one). Although, I guess it is interesting to think if we can find a global example.

Comment: Oh, on a second thought your solution can be easily modified into a global one, by replacing $f$ outside $(-a,a)$ with the constant values $f(-a),f(a)$ respectively.

Comment: But the derivative is bounded.$$f'(x)=1+2\,x\sin(x^{-1})-\cos(x^{-2}),\quad x\ne0.$$ Observe that $x\sin(x^{-1})$ is bounded.